# Show an html string in page

Tags: html, css

I know this has been asked before here. But let me put my problem in a different way. I am using PHP and would like to show a HTML string coming from database in my page. But the problem is as the CSS of the page is of a generic style, it's taking the them in the HTML string also. But I want it to show without **any styling** whatsoever. I have gone through some searching the internet only to find about the "not" selector of CSS. I would like to know whether there is a way to identify a single element in my html page that would “not” take the general styling/css? What “not” does is specify all other element and “not” the one in the argument. I just want the opposite.

```
<style>
.div-class p{font-weight: bold;}
.div-class p:not(.no-style){font-weight: normal;}
</style>

<div class="div-class">
<p>This should be bold.</p>
<p class="no-style">This should not be bold.</p>
</div>
```

I would like the “p” with the “no-style” class to have a normal font weight. It’s currently the opposite. I hope to have made myself clear.

Thanks,

Comment: You can wrap your code (which you don't want to render) inside <pre> tags

Comment: maybe use an `iframe`

Comment: Alen : <pre> tags will show the tags in my html string as is. I dont want that. I want HTML to render the string as HTML, just not take any css from the common page css.
@manta : Iframe would have been an option, but can how do I put my html within it? As far as I know it only takes another page as its source. But I dont have any page, just an HTML sting. am I missing something here?

Comment: @PratipGhosh “<pre> tags will show the tags in my html string as is” No, it does not do that. However, using `<pre>` here isn’t really a solution anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may place your script output in div with certain id/class. And reset css to this div. There are a lot of various css resets available.

P.S. IMHO there is no css rule to disable all css for certain elements.

P.P.S. You may create an empty iframe (`src="about:blank"`) and place your content there with javascript.

Comment: Hmm, i thought so, answer accepted. It will be a bit lengthy approach to reset the tags, however, me too think thats the only option...

Comment: Didnt get you on the iframe thing. Can you please give a small example?

Comment: @PratipGhosh A quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KPJmp/8/ Hovever there are issues with background, in Firefox and Opera it does not changed to default. So I'm not quite sure now if it will reset all the css rules.

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/L0UQfhHr](http://pastebin.com/L0UQfhHr) works great in Chrome and IE but not in FF.

Comment: @PratipGhosh I have updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/KPJmp/10/
You may also use `ifr.contentWindow.document.write()`

Comment: Thanks, `ifr.src="javascript:'"+content+"'"` this is working great too in IE, Chrome and FF :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.div-class p
{
font-weight: bold;
}
.div-class p.no-style
{
font-weight: normal;
}
</style>

<div class="div-class">
<p>This should be bold.</p>
<p class="no-style">This should not be bold.    </p>
</div>
```

Edit: see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/C3jqc/

Edit 2: you can't avoid heritage. You could use "not" in your CSS in this way:

```
<style>
p:not(.unstyled){
font-weight : bold;
}
</style>


<p> this should be Bold</p>
<p class='unstyled'> This shouldn't be bold</p>
```

Then add the "unstyled" class to every content you create from your PHP and the ":not(.styled)" to every CSS declaration.

Another option is to redefine every style in your CSS to match my original response.

Bear in mind the availability of the "not" selector across browsers.

Comment: this was just a sample i provided. The problem with this approach is, I can be having all sorts of tags in my string, not just a p tag. So the solution should not be limited to some tags. Hope I clear myself a little more.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple way to override the styles applied 
you can use `!important`

for example

```
p{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

will not be applied if  u have

```
.nostyle
{
font-weight:normal !important;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C3jqc/2/)